# How to temporarily disable slug creation in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony controller, I have two actions, addCompanyAction and editCompanyAction

I have installed Gedmo slug extension and enabled it in my Company.php entity:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name", "city"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

I need to create a slug when I am using addCompanyAction, but I also need to keep  old slug when I am using editCompanyAction.

How can I temporarily disable slug creation in editCompanyAction? Things like

```
$currentSlug = $company->getSlug();
//... $form = $this->createForm(...) etc...
$company->setSlug($currentSlug);
```

does not work.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Is the slug a part of your formType?

Comment: What about the updatable=false in the Slug annotation definition ?

Comment: @Mcsky oh, thank you! it's working now

Comment: @Mcsky you should post your answer as `answer` not as a `comment`

Comment: I posted my answer, thank to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `updatable=false` configuration of the `@Gedmo\Slug` annotation.

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#some-other-configuration-options-for-slug-annotation)